# Fastest way to remove reciprocal relationships in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cyclic-reference

I imported a thesaurus with duplicate "Related Term" relationships so  when A and B are related, my graph contains  (A)-[:RT]->(B) as well as (B)-[:RT]->(A)

To clean this up, because Neo4j allows me to traverse the graph in both directions, I did

```
match (t0)-[r0:RT]->(t1)-[r1:RT]->(t2)
where t0=t2 AND id(r0) > id(r1)
delete r0
```

Is this the fastest way ? Answer : No, because it can be simplified.

Edited into

```
match (t0)-[r0:RT]->(t1)-[r1:RT]->(t0)
where id(r0)>id(r1)
delete r0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cypher the relationships are unique in each path so unless you break up the query into two separate matches, `r1` and `r2` will never bind the same relationship.

```
MATCH (t0)-[r:RT]->(t1)-[:RT]->(t0)
DELETE r
```

Besides, the relationships declared in your pattern have different direction with regards to `(t0)`, so they can't bind the same relationship for that reason also. You can see this if you break the query up.

```
MATCH (t0)-[r1:RT]->(t1), (t0)<-[r2:RT]-(t1)
```

**Addendum**
As you pointed out in a comment, a pattern like this ends up deleting both relationships after all. This is incidental–each individual match will behave as above and only one relationship is deleted. The reason the query as a whole deletes both relationships is that the pattern is symmetric, i.e. a node will satisfy the pattern in the place designated `t0` if and only if it also satisfies the pattern in the place designated `t1`, or (semi-formally)

```
(t0)-[:RT]->(t1)-[:RT]->(t0) iff (t1)-[:RT]->(t0)-[:RT]->(t1)
```

Perhaps I should have said that `r1` and `r2` can never bind the same relationship at the same time, or in the same match or path. The solution is to break the symmetry. I imagined a local query with a discriminating property

```
(t0 {name:"t0"})-[r:RT]->(t1)-[:RT]->(t0) 
DELETE r
```

but for a global query, if you want to do it all at once, comparing id on `t0` and `t1` is great. Which is exactly the answer you had arrived at already.

Comment: If what you say is correct, then I don't understand the following: create nodes / relations as follows: CREATE (n1) CREATE (n2) CREATE (n1)-[:XYZ]->(n2) CREATE (n2)-[:XYZ]->(n1) then MATCH (t0)-[r:XYZ]->(t1)-[:XYZ]->(t0) DELETE r deletes both [:XYZ] relations, not just one of them.

Comment: I was thinking your actual query would have properties to identify `t0` or `t1`. You are right, if you run the query with 'anonymous' nodes, each node that is bound as `t0` will later also be bound as `t1`. For each match only one relationship is deleted, but since the same path is matched in reverse the other relationship is deleted too. In that case a comparison on ID will make the nodes (or rels) non-anonymous, the 'mirror pattern' will be excluded and only one relationship deleted. I'll update my answer when I have a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this:

```
match (s:Node)-[r]-(n:Node) 
with s,n,type(r) as t, tail(collect(r)) as coll 
foreach(x in coll | delete x)
```

it will remove duplicate and reciprocal relationships regardless of the direction of the edges; However, if you want to specify direction, you can also try:

```
match (s:Node)-[r]->(n:Node) 
with s,n,type(r) as t, tail(collect(r)) as coll 
foreach(x in coll | delete x)
```

or the other way around.
Hope this helps.

Comment: To reviewers: as indicated by Dee Lu himself, this is same as what @Michael Hunger has already answered. hence, this needs to be closed.

Comment: @Sri.U I disagree. This answer contains more information than the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think where clause wont be required.

```
match (t0)-[r0:RT]->(t1)-[r1:RT]->(t0)
delete r0
```

Comment: your suggestion would delete both relationships ;) but referring to the t0 again would simplify the query anyway and thus will it be faster

Comment: It won't delete both as direction of bothrelations are different . So in above query rel r0 frm t0 to t1 will be deleted

Comment: If what you say is correct, then I don't understand the following:

create nodes / relations as follows: 

CREATE (n1)
CREATE (n2)
CREATE (n1)-[:XYZ]->(n2)
CREATE (n2)-[:XYZ]->(n1)

then 

MATCH (t0)-[r0:XYZ]->(t1)-[r1:XYZ]->(t0) DELETE r0

deletes both [:XYZ] relations, not just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like this:

```
match (t0)-[r:RT]-(t1)
with t0,t1, collect(r) as rels
forach (r in tail(rels) | delete r)
```